# Как стилизовать картинку в base64

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, base64

Всем привет, есть картинка с макета в кодировке base64. Надо что бы при наведении на эту картинку у нее менялся цвет. Приемы как с обычным svg не работают.

Comment: Перевести её в `svg` формат и редактировать. Где и как вы хотите редактировать `svg`?

Comment: копируем ВСЁ от кавычки до кавычки - вставляем в адресную стоку -Enter  открываем ИНСПЕКТОР - наводим на тег SVG и Edit as HTML после чего ctrl+c и вставляем куда надо ctrl+v а дальше обычные правила css => это:hover то {fill: такой то}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменить цвет изображения в формате base64 можно только с помощью фильтров CSS или SVG
Например фильтр svg красного цвета

### SVG фильтры

```css
#image0:hover {
filter:url(#RedFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="31px" viewBox="0 0 22 31" enable-background="new 0 0 22 31" xml:space="preserve">
 <defs>
 <filter id="RedFilter" width="32" height="32">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
</defs> 
  <image id="image0" width="22" height="31" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAfCAMAAADUZc3BAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN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"/> 


 
</svg>
```

С помощью SVG фильтров можно покрасить изображение base64 практически в любой цвет

*Ниже пример с тремя цветами покраски при наведении курсора:*

```css
.R1:hover {
filter:url(#RedFilter);
} 

.G1:hover {
filter:url(#GreenFilter);
}
.B1:hover {
filter:url(#BlueFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="150" viewBox="0 -30 400 150" style="border:1px solid grey;"> 

  <defs>
 <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    <filter id="GreenFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    
    <filter id="BlueFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    
    <filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 


   <image id="Building" width="100" height="100"  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>   
   </defs> 
    
   <use class="R1" id="BuildingRed" xlink:href="#Building" x="20" y="0"   ></use> 
   <use class="G1" id="BuildingGreen" xlink:href="#Building" x="150" y="0"  ></use> 
    <use class="B1" id="BuildingBlue" xlink:href="#Building" x="280" y="0"  ></use>
   
   
</svg>
```

### CSS фильтры

При наведении курсора меняет цвет с зелёного с переходом на красный цвет.

Если переход мешает, уберите `transition:1s;`

```css
.img {
transition:1s;
}
.img:hover {
 -webkit-filter: invert(19%) sepia(97%) saturate(5413%) hue-rotate(355deg) brightness(94%) contrast(122%);
filter: invert(19%) sepia(97%) saturate(5413%) hue-rotate(355deg) brightness(94%) contrast(122%);
```

```html
<svg class="img" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="31px" viewBox="0 0 22 31">


 <g>
   <image  width="22" height="31" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAfCAMAAADUZc3BAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN
AAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAA0lBMVEV8tz7///98tz58tz58
tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58
tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58
tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58
tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz58tz7///81N+2GAAAARHRSTlMAABNvuusHgPQczBjcBMVx/sOT
cArsySxcx6j6IN+p/WprWfty1541n0zeGuVWA2W/BuBYATL8jgzdPYkFyCHx8FSKuAwJC38AAAAB
YktHRAH/Ai3eAAAAB3RJTUUH4gEWDCEykhiM3QAAARxJREFUKM9l0ud2gkAQBeCrgh2DBgvWxBJj
w95Lou77P1OcWWCBzA9m7ncO5cwCcMUTmi6EriXiMS7GZCot3Eqnkh5nsiJQ2YzkXF6EKp8jNgoi
UgXjxW9yNoulUtGU83sMVpmnSpXeUq1wKFuo8WBb8kMtm2MNdWqNJtxqNijX0aLWhl9tyi10qH0o
/qTcAT+rq7jLgB5d+4r7lHsYUNMUa5QH+OKbhp4OOX5jxH08kToZcxzBkIuazhzAmU3lsgxg7i5I
Xyx0d5y/VrVcRTe4WtK+11Fe8zFs7LDaG3lo211Qd1vviPdB3vsnfzgqPR58xsn01Dyp/wQ4e3yO
BflylXq9hBi3H9LfG8KMO/EdUcZDiAf+s/N8Oj7/AfO/XwhVAjUTAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0
ZQAyMDE4LTAxLTIyVDEyOjMzOjUwLTA3OjAwy6wQzAAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAxOC0w
MS0yMlQxMjozMzo1MC0wNzowMLrxqHAAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEltYWdlUmVhZHlx
yWU8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/> 
</g>
 
</svg>
```

### NOTE

Фильтры и их параметры для обеспечения нужного цвета можно получить с помощью утилиты  CodePen
[CSS filter generator to convert from black to target hex color](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

### JS + CSS filter

Для изменения цвета `click` по буквам

```html
<img id="img" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/ca.svg" style="cursor:pointer" width="200" height="200" >

<script>
let angle = 120;
img.addEventListener("click",()=>{
   angle *= -1;
  img.style.cssText = `filter:hue-rotate(${angle}deg);cursor:pointer;`
  })
</script>
```